# How pull and delete all images except lastest with python docker sdk?

Tags: python, docker, dockerpy

It needed to run fresh docker image but without download it every time and delete outdatedd images. The algorithm is:

- docker_client.pull()
- docker_client.prune()
- docker_client.run()

The problem is - `prune` which deletes already downloaded image. If `prune` is moved on the top - `pull` command will alwas download new image because all of them deleted with `prune`. Is there a way to setup `pull` to fetch only new latest image and `prune` to keep latest image only?

Answer (score 0):

prune has one argument and its is `prune(filters=None)` so you can use :

> until (timestamp) - only remove containers, images, and networks
>   created before given timestamp

see [this](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/images.html#docker.models.images.ImageCollection.prune) and [this](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/system_prune/#filtering)